# Datepicker didn't work in modal page without adding js code (.Net MVC4)

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, datepicker, modal-dialog

I have some problem with modal and datepicker.
I already try to googled for it and try some of the suggestion but still didn't solved my problem.

I use template from the internet, and use shared layout for sidebar / header&footer.
I put all my css/js render script in my shared layout.
I use another file for my modal, so there's 3 cshtml file for 1 page (Shared layout, main page, modal page)

Here's the code that I use for datepicker :

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" data-plugin-datepicker class="form-control">
```

This code works fine in the main page without adding any js code, but when the modal pops up it didn't shows anything if I don't put a js script inside the modal file.

I have to use this code to make the datepicker working in my modal page :

```
<script>
        $(function () {
              $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
</script>
```

Is there's anything wrong with this?

And I can't change the date format from mm/dd/yyyy into dd-mm-yyyy.

I already use this code :

```
<script>
        $(function () {
              $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
        });
</script>
```

Anyone knows why the format not working?

Thanks
Felix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datepicker will only work on a page if you:
1) import a javascript file containing the datepicker javascript code on that page
2) you put the javascript code on the page like you said in your question.

On your main page I am assuming the datepicker works because there is a javascript file (something.js) get imported to your main page by some line like this:

```
<script src="something.js"></script>
```

Inside this something.js, there is the same javascript code that makes your datepicker work. So that's why you don't need to do the 2) option on your main page.

But on your modal page, there isn't a line like that, so that's why you need to put the

```
<script>
  $(function () {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

to make it work, or you can import the javascript file to your modal page to make it work.

Comment: Hi pythonhiew, yup I think this is the problem. I have to call the javascript again in my modal page. Thanks :).. Btw do you know why the dateFormat is not working?

Comment: Ohh I already have the answer, I change it in bootstrap-datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, I think your problem is that you only have one matching id for the corresponding javascript code. Meaning your id="datepicker" can only be used once

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" data-plugin-datepicker class="form-control">
```

with this code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
          $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

To make it work, you should do another javascript and use another id value for the another datepicker on your page:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker2" data-plugin-datepicker class="form-control">
```

and

```
<script>
    $(function () {
          $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

or you can put this code below in your javascript file:

```
$(function() {

  for (i = 0; i <= 100000; i++) {
    $( "#datepicker"+i ).datepicker();
  }
});
```

and then use these below on your different html pages:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker3" data-plugin-datepicker class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="datepicker4" data-plugin-datepicker class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="datepicker5" data-plugin-datepicker class="form-control">
```

and so on, up until 100000:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker100000" data-plugin-datepicker class="form-control">
```

The html id is unique, you cannot use it repeatedly.

Comment: Hi pythonhiew, thanks for your answer. But I only use that datepicker once and it's still not working.

Comment: It's not working by not taking the date when you submit the form? Or the datepicker doesn't show?

Comment: The datepicker doesn't show up if I dont put JS code in my modal file. But the datepicker shows up if I try it on the main page file even I don't put any jd code there.